# How to configure upstart for OpenVPN instance which is using the down-root plugin

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

- Ubuntu 14.04
- OpenVPN 2.3.2
- Init daemon: upstart

server config file:

```
topology net30
mode server
tls-server
push "route-gateway 192.168.0.1"
ifconfig 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
ifconfig-pool 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.9

port 1196
proto udp
dev tun
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/devops.log 1
syslog vpn-devops
verb 15
writepid /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid
ca /etc/openvpn/devops/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/devops/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/devops/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/devops.ipp
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/devops/ccd
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/devops/crl.pem
client-to-client
```

Problem: whenever restarting the service, I saw this in the log file:

```
May 17 14:32:08 t-xhyve vpn-devops[21013]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
May 17 14:32:08 t-xhyve vpn-devops[21013]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
May 17 14:32:08 t-xhyve vpn-devops[21013]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2
May 17 14:32:08 t-xhyve vpn-devops[21013]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

The reason is OpenVPN is running as `nobody` user which don't have permission to delete the tunnel interface. So, I would like to use the [down-root](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/src/plugins/down-root/README.down-root) plugin to call a down script with root privileges.

```
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so /usr/share/openvpn/down.sh
```

/usr/share/openvpn/down.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/ip addr del dev $1 local $4 peer $5
```

then try to restart but I got this:

```
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23228]: PKCS#11: __pkcs11h_forkFixup entry pid=23228, activate_slotevent=1
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23228]: PKCS#11: __pkcs11h_forkFixup return
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: PLUGIN_CALL: PRE type=PLUGIN_DOWN
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[0] = '/usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[1] = 'tun1'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[2] = '1500'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[3] = '1542'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[4] = '192.168.0.1'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[5] = '192.168.0.2'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ARGV[6] = 'init'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[0] = 'dev=tun1'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[1] = 'link_mtu=1542'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[2] = 'tun_mtu=1500'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[3] = 'script_context=init'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[4] = 'signal=sigterm'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[5] = 'redirect_gateway=0'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[6] = 'dev_type=tun'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[7] = 'ifconfig_remote=192.168.0.2'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[8] = 'ifconfig_local=192.168.0.1'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[9] = 'config=/etc/openvpn/devops/config'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[10] = 'verb=15'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[11] = 'daemon=0'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[12] = 'daemon_log_redirect=0'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[13] = 'daemon_start_time=1463471367'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[14] = 'daemon_pid=23001'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[15] = 'proto_1=udp'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[16] = 'local_port_1=1196'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ENVP[17] = 'remote_port_1=1196'
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so/PLUGIN_DOWN status=1
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_DOWN failed with status 1: /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ERROR: up/down plugin call failed
May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: Exiting due to fatal error
May 17 14:49:50 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
May 17 14:49:50 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
```

I have some questions:

1. Why OpenVPN still call this?

   ```
   /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2
   ```
2. Why do I got this?

   ```
   May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: ERROR: up/down plugin call failed
   May 17 14:49:47 t-xhyve vpn-devops[23001]: Exiting due to fatal error
   May 17 14:49:50 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
   May 17 14:49:50 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
   ```

How to solve it?

---

> Are there any app-armor profiles in place?

No.

> Try modifying the shell script to do cat /proc/self/status >/tmp/temp.txt and printing out the result here.

/usr/share/openvpn/down.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /proc/self/status >/tmp/temp.txt
#/sbin/ip addr del dev $1 local $4 peer $5
```

when restarting:

```
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[18520]: PKCS#11: __pkcs11h_forkFixup entry pid=18520, activate_slotevent=1
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[18520]: PKCS#11: __pkcs11h_forkFixup return
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: PLUGIN_CALL: PRE type=PLUGIN_DOWN
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[0] = '/usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[1] = 'tun1'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[2] = '1500'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[3] = '1542'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[4] = '192.168.0.1'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[5] = '192.168.0.2'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ARGV[6] = 'init'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[0] = 'dev=tun1'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[1] = 'link_mtu=1542'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[2] = 'tun_mtu=1500'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[3] = 'script_context=init'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[4] = 'signal=sigterm'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[5] = 'redirect_gateway=0'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[6] = 'dev_type=tun'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[7] = 'ifconfig_remote=192.168.0.2'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[8] = 'ifconfig_local=192.168.0.1'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[9] = 'config=/etc/openvpn/devops/config'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[10] = 'verb=15'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[11] = 'daemon=0'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[12] = 'daemon_log_redirect=0'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[13] = 'daemon_start_time=1463564660'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[14] = 'daemon_pid=17930'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[15] = 'proto_1=udp'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[16] = 'local_port_1=1196'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ENVP[17] = 'remote_port_1=1196'
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so/PLUGIN_DOWN status=1
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_DOWN failed with status 1: /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: ERROR: up/down plugin call failed
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve vpn-devops[17930]: Exiting due to fatal error
May 18 16:51:00 t-xhyve [2016-05-18 16:51:00,738][WARN ]May 18 16:51:01 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
May 18 16:51:01 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
```

The process restarted but the log file (`/tmp/temp.txt`) was not created.

Sure, running that script manually worked fine:

```
bash -x /usr/share/openvpn/down.sh
 + cat /proc/self/status
 + 

cat /tmp/temp.txt
Name:   cat
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   19246
Ngid:   0
Pid:    19246
PPid:   19245
...
```

---

Specifying the full path didn't help:

```
May 19 03:52:11 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
May 19 03:52:11 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
May 19 03:52:11 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: BACKGROUND: INIT command='/bin/cat /proc/self/status > /tmp/temp.txt'
```

---

> How are you starting/stopping the service?

@rda: here's the upstart file:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345]
          and started rsyslog)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 6 60

pre-start script
    if [ ! -e /var/run/openvpn ]; then
        mkdir -m 0770 /var/run/openvpn
        chown nobody:nogroup /var/run/openvpn
    fi
end script

exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config
post-stop exec sleep 5
```

---

> An alternative script without using `start-stop-daemon`, which sends `SIGTERM` to the main process in an `pre-stop` script stanza, could look as follows:

I added a `pre-stop` script as you suggested:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345]
          and started rsyslog)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 6 60

env PIDFILE="/var/run/openvpn/devops.pid"

pre-start script
    if [ ! -e /var/run/openvpn ]; then
        mkdir -m 0770 /var/run/openvpn
        chown nobody:nogroup /var/run/openvpn
    fi
end script

exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config

pre-stop script
  PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
  kill -15 $PID
  sleep 1
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    rm -f $PIDFILE
  else
    echo "Unable to stop VPN '$NAME'"
  fi
end script

post-stop exec sleep 5
```

then I tried to restart using `restart openvpn-devops` and still got this:

```
May 25 02:41:54 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
May 25 02:41:54 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
May 25 02:41:54 t-xhyve openvpn-devops-upstart: DOWN-ROOT: BACKGROUND: INIT command='/bin/cat /proc/self/status > /tmp/temp.txt'
```

Comment: Are there any app-armor profiles in place? Additionally it might be useful to determine the processes capabilities and re-test. Try modifying the shell script to do `cat /proc/self/status >/tmp/temp.txt` and printing out the result here.

Comment: What do you mean by "Additionally it might be useful to determine the processes capabilities"? I answered your questions by updating the original post.

Comment: I guess you could try `/bin/cat` as it could inherit no paths..

Comment: I tried it without success. The reason seems to be this `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted` and the next line `DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process`.

Comment: @quanta, sounds like this issue here: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/581. May be you can try upgrading to latest openvpn and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your `upstart` scripts. I also included the full OpenVPN config this time. The proposed solution should work, at least it does on my Ubuntu 14.04. Please go though my **whole** answer once again and check your configuration carefully. Please note, with those `upstart` scripts the `writepid` directive in the OpenVPN configuration **is** required (I changed this in my answer). Please also check the line with the `plugin` directive, I suspect you have something wrong there from previous debugging. I'll add an additional troubleshooting section to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer the questions in reverse order:

## 2. Why do I get this?

> `DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process`

When the `down-root` plugin is used, the main process will `fork()` before it drops the root privileges. The module will then remain in a wait state until it receives a message from the main process via pipe to execute the down-script (see [readme](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/tree/master/src/plugins/down-root)). The main process will send this message to the `down-root` module's process when it receives `SIGTERM`.

As mentioned in this OpenVPN [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=792907) with the `systemd` service configuration file, this error is most likely caused in conjunction with `upstart` (the default init daemon used by ubuntu 14.04), which will send `SIGTERM` to both processes. The `down-root` module's process will terminate, before it has a chance to do its job, calling the down-script.

Use the **`/etc/init.d/openvpn`** shipped with Ubuntu to start and stop the service or fix it in the `upstart` script. A very simple working upstart script could look as follows. Note that it uses `start-stop-daemon` to send the correct signals.

Create a file `/etc/init/openvpn.conf`

```bash
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345]
          and started rsyslog)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 6 60

env PIDFILE="/var/run/openvpn/devops.pid"

pre-start script
    if [ ! -e /var/run/openvpn ]; then
        mkdir -m 0770 /var/run/openvpn
        chown nobody:nogroup /var/run/openvpn
    fi
end script

exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
  --pidfile /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid \
  --exec /usr/sbin/openvpn -- --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config < /dev/null

pre-stop script
  exec start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo \
    --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --retry 5
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    rm -f $PIDFILE
  else
    echo "Unable to stop VPN"
  fi
end script

post-stop exec sleep 5
```

An **alternative** script without using `start-stop-daemon`, which sends `SIGTERM` to the main process in a `pre-stop` script stanza, could look as follows:

```bash
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345]
          and started rsyslog)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 6 60

env PIDFILE="/var/run/openvpn/devops.pid"

pre-start script
    if [ ! -e /var/run/openvpn ]; then
        mkdir -m 0770 /var/run/openvpn
        chown nobody:nogroup /var/run/openvpn
    fi
end script

exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config

pre-stop script
  PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
  kill -15 $PID
  sleep 1
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    rm -f $PIDFILE
  else
    echo "Unable to stop VPN"
  fi
end script

post-stop exec sleep 5
```

Controlling the `upstart` job:

```
initctl <command> openvpn
```

- **`<command>`**: `start`, `stop`, `restart`

This should remove the error above and run the `down.sh` script correctly, but the following error will still show up:

```
Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
```

This error occurs in the first place, because `ip addr del` is executed after the TUN/TAP interface has already been closed.

More on this below.

---

## 1. Why does OpenVPN still call this?

> `/sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 192.168.0.1 peer 192.168.0.2`

This is caused by the directive `ifconfig`, which will add/del the IP-address of the TUN/TAP interface when starting/stopping the service. (See [manpage](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage))

To circumvent this behavior, modify the configuration as follows.

**OpenVPN server configuration** file:

```
topology net30
mode server
tls-server
push "route-gateway 192.168.0.1"
ifconfig 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
ifconfig-pool 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.9
ifconfig-noexec
up /usr/share/openvpn/up.sh
down-pre
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so /usr/share/openvpn/down.sh
script-security 2
port 1196
proto udp
dev tun
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/devops.log 1
syslog vpn-devops
verb 15
writepid /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid
ca /etc/openvpn/devops/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/devops/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/devops/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/devops.ipp
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/devops/ccd
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/devops/crl.pem
client-to-client
```

- **`ifconfig-noexec`**: Don't execute ifconfig commands, pass `--ifconfig` parameters to scripts.
- **`up`**: Running an up-script to set an IP-address is required due to `ifconfig-noexec`
- **`down-pre`**: Call `--down` script before, rather than after, TUN/TAP close.
- **`script-security 2`**: Allow calling of built-in executables and user-defined scripts.

**UP script** `/usr/share/openvpn/up.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/ip addr add dev $1 local $4 peer $5
/sbin/ip link set dev $1 up
```

**DOWN script** `/usr/share/openvpn/down.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/ip addr del dev $1 local $4 peer $5
/sbin/ip link set dev $1 down
```

The UP / DOWN scripts will also bring the interface up and down (although not required).

Make sure they are executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/share/openvpn/up.sh
chmod +x /usr/share/openvpn/down.sh
```

---

### Alternatively use a persistent TUN interface

**OpenVPN server configuration** file (edit/add those lines):

```
dev tun1
# down-pre
```

- **`dev tun1`**: We'll be using a persistent TUN interface
- **`# down-pre`**: Not required using persistent interface

Finally create a **persistent TUN interface**:

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tun1
```

This builds a persistent tunnel `tun1` that lives through multiple instantiations of  OpenVPN and dies only when it is deleted with `openvpn --rmtun --dev tun1` or the machine is rebooted.

---

## Troubleshooting

Here are some additional troubleshooting steps if the configuration is correct as shown above and the following error still shows up:

```
DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process
```

Start the OpenVPN instance, i.e. with `upstart`:

```
initctl start openvpn
```

Check what `PID` the processes have:

```
ps -ef | grep "[o]penvpn"

# or more specific for our devops server example
ps -ef | grep "[o]penvpn/devops"

# this should show 2 openvpn processes
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nobody    3590     1  0 21:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config
root      3593  3590  0 21:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config
```

While tailing the logs, **kill** the main openvpn process (running as user `nobody`) manually with `SIGTERM` using its `PID`

```
kill -15 3590
```

Or **alternatively** in a single line:

```
kill -15 `ps -ef | grep "^[n]obody .* /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config$" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

The condensed log output should look like this (without the `DOWN-ROOT: Error ...`):

```
vpn-devops[3590]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
vpn-devops[3590]: PLUGIN_CALL: PRE type=PLUGIN_DOWN
upstart-devops  : DOWN-ROOT: BACKGROUND: received command code: 0
vpn-devops[3590]: PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so/PLUGIN_DOWN status=0
vpn-devops[3590]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
vpn-devops[3590]: PLUGIN_CLOSE: /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-down-root.so
vpn-devops[3590]: PID packet_id_free
vpn-devops[3590]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
upstart-devops  : DOWN-ROOT: close
upstart-devops  : DOWN-ROOT: BACKGROUND: received command code: 1
upstart-devops  : DOWN-ROOT: BACKGROUND: EXIT
kernel: init    : ovpn-devops main process ended, respawning
```

Comment: I saw that bug but I thought that it's not related since I have no systemd configuration file in `/etc/systemd/system/`. I updated my original question to reply to your first suggestion to fix this error `DOWN-ROOT: Error sending script execution signal to background process`.

Comment: It is definitely kind of related to the `systemd` bug in OpenVPN prior to 2.3.7, as it shows the same behaviour on Debian 8.4. You can further troubleshoot the `upstart` stop sequence, by tracing both openvpn processes separately using `strace -tt -p <pid>`. Look for the `--- SIGTERM` signals and compare the timings of both `strace` outputs. Without the `pre-stop script`, sending `SIGTERM` only to the unprivileged process, both processes are terminated by upstart almost simultaneously. You may have to increase `sleep 1` if the down-script takes longer than one second to finish on your system.